# 'onchange' starts only one java script

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have a "select" drop down, with 2 "onchange" actions attached

```
echo "<select id='selecttask' name='task' onchange='showpcaction(this.value);showpcinterview(this.value);'>";
echo "<option disabled selected>";
while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
echo "<option value='".$row['TASK_NAME']."'>".$row['TASK_NAME']."`</option>";}
echo "</select>";`
```

the problem is that only ONE (it's always the sedond one) is actually started. I can get one of them to start but not BOTH.
I did this before with no problems so not sure what's up.

here are the 2 java scripts:

```
function showpcinterview(task_name) {            

if (task_name == 'Interview'){

          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("pc_interview").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","showpcinterview.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

} 

else{
document.getElementById("pc_interview").innerHTML ="";

}
}


              function showpcaction(task_name) {


          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("pc_action").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","showpcaction.php?task_name=" + task_name,true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}
```

Comment: also, if I replace one of the js functions in the "onchange" with a simpler one like this:  
function testjs(test){
  alert(test);} 
it will execute BOTH , but it will NOT execute both in the original question

Comment: I'd guess it's because you're using the same `xmlhttp` variable in both functions - the second is overwriting the first.  I don't know for sure (hence a comment, not an answer) what happens to the callbacks etc attached to the first when you throw away the reference to it, but there's a good chance it'll be garbage collected and they'll never fire.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah I kinda worded it badly - I'll remove my comment and re-add with a better explanation :) ah I see you pretty much said what I was trying to say 6mins ago haha ! no need to comment :) though again I'll reiterate - no inline JS! :) also it's JavaScript scripts - don't get them confused with Java Scripts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simply declare your xmlhttp within your functions scope by using the var keyword.

In your case, as no var statement is present, the object is global and so, declared a first time in your first function, placing a listener and sending the request, but then imlmediately in your second function you redeclare this object, thus killing the readystate listener.

So just declare your object like this in both functions: var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I shall toast your name tonight with my heartiest wine!